# Brew Install Rtorrent not Working

Tags: homebrew

I am unable to brew build rtorrent. Could someone tell me what I need to do to get this to work?

Things I have done -

```
brew doctor
brew update
brew upgrade --all
```

Error -

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [rtorrent] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
==> Formula
Path: /usr/local/Library/Formula/rtorrent.rb
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
HEAD: 45bc689b2a1af15c798fa01481b38da062e47e3f
Last commit: 53 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: 8-core 64-bit haswell
OS X: 10.10.3-x86_64
Xcode: 6.3.2
CLT: 6.3.2.0.1.1431401888
Clang: 6.1 build 602
X11: 2.7.7 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 2.0.0-p481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_40
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: gcc-5
HOMEBREW_CXX: g++-5
MAKEFLAGS: -j8
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libtorrent/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin

Logs:
     /Users/aaron/Library/Logs/Homebrew/rtorrent/01.configure
     /Users/aaron/Library/Logs/Homebrew/rtorrent/01.configure.cc
     /Users/aaron/Library/Logs/Homebrew/rtorrent/02.make
     /Users/aaron/Library/Logs/Homebrew/rtorrent/02.make.cc
     /Users/aaron/Library/Logs/Homebrew/rtorrent/config.log
```

Comment: The errors are in the log before the ld line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am facing the same issue. I believe it is caused by the newly added `gcc v5.1.0` package.

Rolling back to `gcc v4.9.2` solved the installation issue with `rtorrent v0.9.4` package. You can rollback to `gcc v4.9.2` two different methods based on the current state of your homebrew installation.

**Method A**

If you have not performed `brew cleanup` after `brew upgrade --all` then you can simply switch to older version of gcc by running `brew switch gcc 4.9.2`. For further information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/2062000) answer.

**Method B**

Unfortunately if you have a habit of running `brew cleanup` after `brew upgrade --all` (like me ;-(), follow the steps mentioned below to install `gcc v4.9.2` package.

```
brew uninstall gcc
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc49
```

**Final Step**

Install rtorrent by running the below mentioned command in your teminal.

```
brew install rtorrent
```

Comment: The newest released version of rtorrent on brew is now functioning. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Becuase of this issue rtorrent has been moved to the boneyard you now also need to do `brew tap homebrew/boneyard`

Answer (score 0):

> rtorrent is simply removed from Homebrew these days because it's too hard to get to build in El Capitan

Source: https://two-wrongs.com/rtorrent-missing-homebrew-os-x-10-11-el-capitan